# Columns to Row conversion: MySQL

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, concatenation

I have a multitenant model and trying to display an output where a column of one table becomes a row in the output.

I have 3 tables - 1 Data table, 1 Metadata table and an Extension Table.

Here is my query:

```
set @sql=NULL;
SELECT group_concat(CONCAT( 
    'MAX(If(EXTLABEL = ''', EXTLABEL, ''', VALUE, NULL)) AS ',EXTLABEL))
    into @sql
FROM TENANT_METADATA, TENANT_EXTENSIONTABLE
WHERE TENANT_METADATA.EXTENSION_ID = TENANT_EXTENSIONTABLE.EXTENSION_ID;

SET @sql=CONCAT('SELECT TENANT_NAME AS TENANT_TABLE, ', @sql, ' 
                FROM TENANT_DATATABLE, TENANT_METADATA, TENANT_EXTENSIONTABLE 
                WHERE TENANT_DATATABLE.RECORD_ID=TENANT_EXTENSIONTABLE.RECORD_ID
                AND TENANT_METADATA.EXTENSION_ID = TENANT_EXTENSIONTABLE.EXTENSION_ID
                group by TENANT_DATATABLE.TENANT_NAME');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
Execute stmt;
DEALLOCATE prepare stmt;
```

In my output, I need column names as "Tenant_Table, ExtLABEL1, ExtLABEL2, ExtLABEL3 etc.
and the VALUE field should display the values for the EXTLABEL Columns.

My query seems to fetch proper value from different table, but when i execute the Prepare stmt, it says I have a syntax error, but I am unable to identify the mistake. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please show us your syntax error.

Comment: This is what i am getting:12:42:53 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')) AS ID,MAX(If(EXTLABEL = 'DESCRIPTION', VALUE = 'Design Data Models')) AS DESC' at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: Does that error message correspond to the code posted in your question?

Comment: 1064 -- Print out the first @sql value so we can see the query.

Answer (score 0):

Columns to rows:  UNION ALL

```
( SELECT Tenant_Table, 1, ExtLABEL1 AS EXTLABEL FROM ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT Tenant_Table, 2, ExtLABEL2 AS EXTLABEL FROM ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT Tenant_Table, 3, ExtLABEL3 AS EXTLABEL FROM ... )
ORDER BY 1,2;
```